# How profitable are Slime Hutches?

Tags: stardew-valley

Having a full Slime Hutch can create a steady supply of Slime Eggs that can be sold for a nice amount of money, with even the cheapest selling for 1000 gold. Given the different colours of eggs have different drop chances, how much money can I expect to make from a single hutch?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A Slime Egg-Press will create a random egg out of 100 slime:

- Green Slime Egg: 75% chance, 1000 selling price
- Blue Slime Egg: 15% chance, 1750 selling price
- Red Slime Egg: 5% chance, 2500 selling price
- Purple Slime Egg: 5% chance, 5000 selling price

By multiplying the value of each egg by the chance of receiving that egg, and then summing these values, we can calculate the average value of a random egg: 750 + 262.5 + 125 + 250 = 1387.5

A Slime Hutch with 20 slimes will produce an average of 60 slime each day, so the profit per day of a single hutch is 0.6 * 1387.5 = **832.5 gold**

Note that this does not include the Petrified Slime found in slime balls. I can't seem to find an average amount for them.